# How to know 3 points of intersection by providing 2 points in a rectangular area

Tags: actionscript-3, geometry, trigonometry

[image: problem illustrated]

I have this problem in a game. I know points A,B,C,D,S,T. In actionscript 3 i need to know points P1, P2, P3 and if possible the 3 angles forming by the points. After I need to draw lines T:P1, P1:P2, P2:P3

Who can help me with some actionscript 3 code snippet?

thanks in advance

Comment: Beta = Pi/2 - Alpha; Delta = Alpha

Answer (score 2):

Find the intersection of ray ST with ray DA and reflect that point about line segment AB to get point P1. Repeat to get points P2 and P3

Comment: Thanks. It's possible to have some code snippet, i don't know how to intersect and reflect that points.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the time. The point at which two lines intersect can be found by solving the two simultaneous equations for the lines. Reflection of a point in your example is done by subtracting from the relevant X or Y co-ordinate or the line the difference in that co-ordinate from the line to the point to be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don't know any more advanced vector math off the top of my head, but as a geometry problem, but I think it would be possible to solve just using basic trig by breaking down it in to a problem made up of right angle triangles?

The angle created by the points T and S could be found by making a triangle, treating the line TS as the hypotenuse. The 3rd point of that triangle would be (T.x, S.y) or (S.x, T.y).

P1 could then be calculated since you know the angle and the length of the next triangle, the side A.x to T.x. This gives point P as well as the angle beta.

P2 could be calculated by using angle beta and knowing the distance between P1.y to D.y...which forms another leg of the next triangle. This also gives angle delta.

Finally, P3 can be calculated, since you know the angle and the length of 1 side of that triangle: angle delta and line P2.x to C.x.